# Server stuck on SSL, TLS handshake after client response

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ssl, ssl-certificate, handshake

Need a solution,

Server sometimes stuck while a request is made. Request:

```
curl -v -o delete.txt --trace-time https://asd.com/
06:43:46.708926 * Rebuilt URL to: https://asd.com/
06:43:46.709023 * Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     006:43:47.218368 *   Trying 0.0.0.0...
0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     006:43:47.236048 * Connected to asd.com (0.0.0.0) port 443 (#0)06:43:47.237853 * successfully set certificate verify locations:
06:43:47.237898 *   CAfile: none
CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
06:43:47.238039 * SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
06:43:47.238061 } [data not shown]
0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:57 --:--:--     006:44:44.575998 * Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to asd.com:443
```

My certificates:

```
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/cert.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/cert.key
SSLCACertificateFile  /etc/apache2/ssl/cert.ca-bundle
```

Virtual Host configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:443> 
ServerName asd.com 
ServerAlias asd.com 

<Directory /var/www/html> 
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews 
  AllowOverride All 
  Order allow,deny 
  allow from all 
  Require all granted 
</Directory> 

ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.com 
DocumentRoot /var/www/html 

SSLEngine on 
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/cert.crt 
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/cert.key 
SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/cert.ca-bundle 
</VirtualHost>
```

What i am missing, to make it ?

Comment: Can you share VirtualHost (:443) configuration?

Comment: @DusanBajic <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName asd.com
        ServerAlias asd.com


  <Directory /var/www/html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
        Require all granted
  
  
  </Directory>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/cert.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/cert.key
        SSLCACertificateFile  /etc/apache2/ssl/cert.ca-bundle
</VirtualHost>

Comment: You say 'sometimes stuck', does that mean that sometimes that same curl request works fine?

Comment: yes, sometimes it works fine, when it stuck i restart my apache server, it again go live

Comment: Any progress on that problem? May be it's something with the ssl cache configuration.

Comment: @Inceddy just increased my aws instance type, the issue was fixed